# Angular date time calculations gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time, datepicker

Hi im working on calculating time between to dates 
 my code

```
$scope.startTime = new Date('0').setHours(7);
$scope.endTime = new Date('0').setHours(17);
$scope.breakTime = new Date('0').setMinutes(30);     

this.tosum = function(startTime, endTime, breakTime) {
            var timestamp1 = new Date(startTime).getTime();
            var timestamp2 = new Date(endTime).getTime();
            var timestamp3 = new Date(breakTime).getTime();
            var diff = timestamp2 - timestamp1 - timestamp3;
            var newDate = new Date('0');
            newDate.setMilliseconds(diff);
            return newDate;
        };
```

it works with timestamp1 and 2 but when i add, timestamp 3 i get wrong result.. :/

I want to get time between startTime and endTime - breakTime

```
var diff = timestamp2 - timestamp1
```

Gives 10:00  as it should, but when adding `-timestamp1`it gives 10:30 not 9:30 as it should :/

if i add `+ timestamp3;` instead of - i get 9:30 as it should, but then if add one hour to break time, so break time is 1hour 30 min,  i get 10:30 and break time 2 hour 30 min result 11:30 and so one :/ but should be 8:30 and 7:30    how do i correct this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because you haven't taken the reference to your Epoch (the year 2000: you use the string `0` which is parsed using the parser) into account. In pure JS (you can translate it to angular).

```js
function tosum(startTime, endTime, breakTime) {
    var reference = new Date('0'),
        timestamp1 = new Date(startTime).getTime() - reference.getTime(),
        timestamp2 = new Date(endTime).getTime() - reference.getTime(),
        timestamp3 = new Date(breakTime).getTime() - reference.getTime(),
        diff = timestamp2 - timestamp1 - timestamp3,
        newDate = new Date('0');

    newDate.setTime(diff);
    
    return newDate;
}

var startTime = new Date('0').setHours(7),
    endTime = new Date('0').setHours(17),
    breakTime = new Date('0').setMinutes(30);

document.body.textContent = tosum(startTime, endTime, breakTime).toISOString().split(/[T\.]/g)[1];
```

If you had used the unix epoch (by using the number 0 of milliseconds since the epoch) then you would have had no problem.

```js
function tosum(startTime, endTime, breakTime) {
    var timestamp1 = new Date(startTime).getTime(),
        timestamp2 = new Date(endTime).getTime(),
        timestamp3 = new Date(breakTime).getTime(),
        diff = timestamp2 - timestamp1 - timestamp3,
        newDate = new Date(0);

    newDate.setTime(diff);
    
    return newDate;
}

var startTime = new Date(0).setHours(7),
    endTime = new Date(0).setHours(17),
    breakTime = new Date(0).setMinutes(30);

document.body.textContent = tosum(startTime, endTime, breakTime).toISOString().split(/[T\.]/g)[1];
```

Using the `console` and logging a few of your values would have shown you this.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try below:

var diff = timestamp2 - (timestamp1 + timestamp3);

Comment: gives same result, no different :/